# Windsor Resolve with argument dictionary

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle.Windsor in my application. My components and their parameters are configured within the app.config file. But I also want to be able to pass parameters by command line arguments. That means `cmd-args > config-args`. I tried to use `container.Resolve<Class>(dictionary)`. But it did not work (config-args are used). Curiously if I use a anonymous type, it works.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
public class TestB
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public TestB(string a)
    {
        A = a;
        //B = b;
    }
}

         [Test]
    public void Test()
    {

        var dictionary = new Hashtable
                        {
                            { "a", "b" }
                        };

        var anonymousType = new
                            {
                                a = "b"
                            };

        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());

        var opt1 = container.Resolve<TestB>(anonymousType);
        var opt2 = container.Resolve<TestB>(dictionary);

        Assert.That(opt1.A == "b");
        Assert.That(opt2.A == "b");
    }
```

That's freaky. Both assertions succeed. But if I swap opt1 and opt2 resolvations, assertion 2 fails.

Comment: Can you show us your code with the dictionary and with the anonymous type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for that is that the dependency is set twice:
- first as a .ctor parameter
- then again as a property

Windsor does **non**-case-sensitive parameter name matching when matching your parameters from xml config and from anonymous type and the in-line argument you pass takes precedence over xml, just like you would expect.

However you gave it a `Hashtable` that you set up to **be** case-sensitive and Windsor honors that.

So it matches `a` .ctor argument, but then it goes to set `A` property, and the `Hashtable` does not provide a value for that, so it grabs one from you XML.

Regarding

> if I swap opt1 and opt2 resolvations, assertion 2 fails.

You didn't post your xml config but I suspect the lifestyle of the component is singleton, in which case the second call to `Resolve` will just give you the object constructed by the first call, and whatever arguments you pass will be ignored.

Normally you probably would not expose setters for properties being set via .ctor and keep them readonly.

Comment: I not quiet sure why, but after changing accessibility modifier of `set` to private, it works. Normally I always declare property setters as private, but this was just a test, whether it could work for me :) Thanks!

Comment: If you make the property setter private Windsor will not try to set it, therefore the value from xml will not override the value set from the dictionary via .ctor